# Redirect to menu url, not SEF url

Tags: php, joomla

I'm writing a Joomla! component, and after a task is done, I want to redirect the user with a message:

```
$this->setMessage("Your order was placed successfully.");
$this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option='.$this->option.'&view=orders', false));
```

In the browser, this redirects to `http://localhost:64895/component/mycomponent/?view=orders`. I've got a menu item, however, that links to this view, and I normally access the same page at `http://localhost:64895/orders.html`.

Is it possible to get `JRoute` to target this menu item instead of the standard SEF URL?

Comment: there is nothing to redirect with joomla function to the given url if you on your site SEF do try to off SEF url on site and redirect

Comment: try to pass Itemid too.It will select the menu you want